Creating a PC from old parts
I have some laptop parts I would like to use to build a portable computer. These parts are:

2 x RAM 8GB DDR4 3200MHz CL22 SODIMMs;
1 x NGW wireless card; And
1 x Internal HD 2.5 Inch SATA Rev 3.0, 500GB.

Is it possible to build a raspberry device amenable for these components? Are there any recommendations?
Thanks and regards.

It depends on what you want to do with it? Have you found a case to house the pi and drive?

@RohitGupta, thanks for the comment. Basically, I want to have a mini PC, so I can carry around and connect to a portable monitor when convenient. The thing is, what would be the proper raspberry for my case? That is, there exist a raspberry with the support for DDR4 SODIMM, and NGW wireless cards?

IMO the only really valuable thing here is the RAM. I’d look at a N-series minicomputer, barebones, and just stick the RAM in and ignore the rest. It’ll be more expensive than a Pi, but it’ll be substantially quicker. I can provide more specific recommendations if you ping me tomorrow.

@JMY1000, thank you so much, I have searched for the key words you presented, and it they are exactly what I am looking for. I will a look at DIY toturials. Thnx.

All Raspberry Pi models already include RAM on the board, you can't add RAM. All models from Raspberry 3 upwards include Wifi.
It might be possible to connect a SATA HDD through USB, but usually you would just use an SD card or with a Raspberry 5 a NVMe SSD.

Thank you so much.


No. It is not possible to install additional RAM in any version of Raspberry Pi. This is due to, among others, from board design and memory handling capabilities.

Question: why?
Most Rasberry Pis have built-in Wifi, so the question arises: do you want to add a second one?

Yes, it is possible to connect an HDD/SSD via an additional SATA 3 module. The module is called Geekworm X825 v2 and costs about $39. And I would forget about the additional power supply, which is not included with the purchased module



Thank you so much.
